# checking if location.hash exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel that I can change the location of with an integer value.

What I'd like to do is take the hash, remove the `#` symbol and store that value in a variable which I can later use in a function.

I've pasted the code below, which for some reason just won't work.

```
var $hash = window.location.hash;

        if($hash != ''){
            var $grave_nr = $hash.substring(1);
            return $grave_nr;
        } else{
            var $grave_nr = 1;
            return $grave_nr;
        }

        // carousel
        $('#the_graves_carousel').tinycarousel({ 
            intervaltime: 7000,
            pager: true,
            duration: 1600,
            start: $grave_nr
        });
```

Anyone have an idea why it's not working?

**EDIT:** fixed it by removing the `return $grave_nr;` in the if statements :)

Comment: Is the console showing any errors?

Comment: No. I fixed it by removing the `return $grave_nr;`

Comment: Once your call `return`, the function will stop running and any code there-after will not run. Since this isn't an actual question, could you please delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $hash = window.location.hash;
var $grave_nr = $hash ? $hash.slice(1) : 1;

$('#the_graves_carousel').tinycarousel({ 
    intervaltime: 7000,
    pager: true,
    duration: 1600,
    start: $grave_nr
});
```

Comment: hey man, could you explain what the 2nd line of code does?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation